# sequential merging of a large number of png files

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good afternoon, please tell me, how can I combine a large number of files sequentially. For example, there are 5000 png files in folder 1 and 5000 png files in folder 2, you need to sequentially combine them file 1 from folder 1 with file 1 from folder 2, then file 2 from folder 1 with file 2 from folder 2 and so on. The result should be 5000 merged files from folder 1 and 2. Thank you all in advance for your answers and feedback

found information about combining several png files. Information about combining a consistently large number of APGs in a given order, no information was found

to merge means to combine, i.e. to superimpose an image from folder 2 on the background from folder 1, as a result, you should get a third image (combined) consisting of a background and a picture

Comment: You want keywords? openCV, numpy, numpy.concat, os.listdir, python, script...
If you have an attempt to share and tell us what's not working, please give a heads up :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cool - only you didn't tell us how they need to be merged (above+below, left+right, depth-stack)? Nor did you say how they were named? Nor what OS you use? Nor show what code you have tried? Nor include a [mcve]. Please do the [tour] then click [edit] and improve your question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all, they already helped me, though with the help of another program (Imagemagick)
it was just necessary to overlay one image on top of another.

You need to create two folders in one background in two images. The names and size of the images must be the same.

Here's the code:

```bash
for %i in (1\*.png) do magick composite -gravity center "2\%~ni.png" "%i" "%~ni.png"
```